# I'm unable to understand how to borrow an item from a vector mutably in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, mutability

I can't make this code work, I understand I need to change the self reference to a mutable reference but this will just spawn a new set of errors.

```rs
struct Context {
    values: Vec<u32>,
}

trait Adder {
    fn add(&self, context: &Context);
}

struct Container {
    data: Vec<Box<dyn Adder>>,
}

impl Container {
    fn add_one_adder(&mut self, adder: Box<dyn Adder>) {
        self.data.push(adder);
    }
    fn execute(&self, context: &Context) {
        self.data.iter().for_each(|adder| adder.add(context))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let context = Context {
        values: vec![1, 2, 3, 4],
    };

    struct BasicAdder {
        index: usize,
        value: u32,
    };

    impl Adder for BasicAdder {
        fn add(&self, context: &Context) {
            context.values[self.index] = context.values[self.index] + self.value;
            // cannot borrow `context.values` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
            // `context` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
        }
    }

    let mut container = Container { data: vec![] };

    let basic_adder = BasicAdder { index: 0, value: 1 };
    container.add_one_adder(Box::new(basic_adder));
    container.execute(&context);
}
```

snippet link:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=60c5f883fb51b9c8e1fd62864f720de9

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with `self`. It's `context` that needs to be mutable, since that's the variable you're modifying.

```
fn add(&self, context: &mut Context) {
  ...
}
```

You'll need to follow this up the call stack, since whoever calls `add` needs a mutable reference to `Context` now, and so on. When you get all the way back up to `main`, the variable (and its reference) need to be declared mutable.

```
let mut context = Context {
  values: vec![1, 2, 3, 4],
};
...
container.execute(&mut context);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above.. you need mutable referece of `Context` in `impl Adder for BasicAdder`, as you are updating the vector as shown in the answer above, i.e

```
impl Adder for BasicAdder {
    fn add(&self, context: &mut Context) {...}
```

since `add()` function has a parameter of `&mut Context`,so `Adder` trait containing the `add` method should also match the same parameters type;

```
trait Adder {
    fn add(&self, context: &mut Context);
}
```

similarly as you have to pass `&mut Context` as a parameter to `container.execute(&mut context);` in the above answer, we need to accept the parameter as a mutable type in the `execute` method of `impl Container` i.e.

```
impl Container {
   // add_one_adder function..
    fn execute(&self, context: &Context) {...}
}
```

And it will not spawn a new set of errors.
Updated Snippet [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6ede554333ec3080aa36819ccd3d19ad)